# missing value or empty string in enum

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

Is there a way to have an enum like this:

```
classdef(Enumeration) bla_type < int32
    enumeration
        bla_one(1)
        bla_2(2)
    end
end
```

with a missing or NaN value? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NaN values apply to floating-point types, but not integers.  With integers every bit pattern has a numeric meaning.  With floating-point some patterns are reserved for NaNs and infinities.

Since your underlying type for your enum is int32, you won't be able to use NaN.

Comment: if I use < double would I be ok?

Comment: @csetzkorn: I'm not sure if MatLab allows it, but I certainly would try that.